# Probability of pairwise independent event, find its upper bound

Tags: probability

So we were told that the events $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are **pairwise independent** such that $P(A_1)=0.1$, $P(A_2)=0.02$, and $P(A_3)=0.01$.

What is the upper bound for the term $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$?

Answer:
$$
P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) \leq  P(A_2 \cap A_3)=0.02\cdot0.01
$$

This solution doesn't make any sense. Why?

Comment: "the upper bound"? And you are asking us why the solution doesn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution makes perfect sense. For any three events $X,Y,Z$, we have $$P(X\cap Y\cap Z)\le P(Y\cap Z)$$ right? And for any pairwise independent events $Y,Z$, we have $$P(Y\cap Z)=P(Y)P(Z)$$ right? And that's exactly what the answer says, right?

Answer (score 0):

Note that for sets $X,Y,Z$, $X \cap Y \cap Z \subset X \cap Y, X \cap Z, Y \cap Z$.

So, $P(X \cap Y \cap Z) \leq P(X \cap Y) , P(X \cap Z), P(Y \cap Z)$ or equivalently, $P(X \cap Y \cap Z) \leq \min( P(X \cap Y), P(X \cap Z), P(Y \cap Z))$. This follows from the fact that $P(A) \leq P(B)$ if $A \subset B$.

If $X,Y,Z$ are pairwise independent, then $P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y),P(X\cap Z) = P(X) P(Z), P(Y \cap Z) = P(Y) P(Z)$.

Thus, plugging into the previous statement, we have $P(X\cap Y \cap Z) \leq \min(P(X)P(Y),P(X)P(Z),P(Y)P(Z))$. By evaluating each of the terms in the min, we can get a nice lower bound. Alternatively, we can just use one of the terms in the min as a lower bound (but not necessarily the best lower bound of this form.